# android access server database out of two choices

Tags: android, sql-server

i was trying to build an app which takes the data from server database and use it in android app ( in may case for reading the gprs coordinates available on database).

after a lot of search, i came across RESTfull services for implementing this. but there is a simpler way also, that is accessing the server database directly from android app by using a driver (jtds) and running mysql on server side.

i am actually confused which one to use. Why restful service which is highly platform independent and have a wide range or directly accessing the mysql database from server. which is most extensively used and why? giving below examples of both scenarios.

through restful service - http://avilyne.com/?p=105 and directly by accessing sql server database- http://amitku.wordpress.com/2011/08/03/how-to-connect-and-access-sql-database-server-from-android-app/

please let me know which is better and mostly used and why?

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly encourage using the REST approach, and although there are many reasons, two or three come immediately to mind:

1.)  Security.  By using a REST approach, any data on the server side can only be accessed by server-side code, which can provide a protective layer between the data and the outside world.

2.)  Scalability.  A direct connection, such as the example at your link, hooks into a particular instance of a database.  If that database already has a large number of connections, there will be performance issues or worse.

3.)  Server side flexibility.  If the underlying database structure or technology needs to change, a REST approach will allow for that.  All the client side cares about is posting or requesting to a server that will respond via REST protocol.

I would think that a REST approach is much more widely used than a direct client-server approach.